# CSV python sort() only outputting numbers from lowest to highest, not the other way round

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I'm using this code:

```
name = input("Name:")
surname = input("Surname:")
number = input("Number:")

myfile=open("tryout_sorting.csv", "a")
myfile.write(name + "," + surname + "," + number + "\n")
myfile.close()

sample = open("tryout_sorting.csv", "r")
csv1 = csv.reader(sample,delimiter=",")
sort = sorted(csv1, key=lambda t: float( t[2] ))

for eachline in sort:
    print(eachline)
```

I'm trying to store name, surname and number in a csv file and then output their scores from highest to lowest but:

`sorted(csv1, key=lambda t: float( t[2] ))`

is from lowest to highest.

I've also tried:

`sorted(csv1,key=operator.itemgetter(2))`

and:

`sorted(csv1,key=lambda x:float(x[2]))`

but they all output the numbers in order of lowest to highest.

Comment: `sorted` has a further parameter `reverse`. If set to `True`, it sorts the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

`sorted()` uses the `reverse` argument for sorting from highest to lowest. Try:

```
 sorted(csv1, key=float, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

So here is the documentation of sorted: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

It has a flag called 'reverse', try setting it to True :)

Comment: Your answer is correct but I would suggest using embedding link instead of pasting the long URL and also add a sample code using the original code.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry for the inconvenience, was just a quick shot, but there's already another answer doing the exact same thing so i think i'll leave it as it is